# scala - Functional way to take a string and create a dictionary using specific delimiters

Tags: scala, functional-programming, mapping

For instance if this is the string I have

```
a|1
b|2
c|3
```

How do I create a dictionary like:

```
dic[a] => 1
dic[b] => 2
dic[c] => 3

tried to do:

string.split("\n").map(_.split("|") ?????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
val str =
  """|a|1
     |b|2
     |c|3""".stripMargin

str
 .split("\\n")
 .map(_.split("\\|"))
 .map { case Array(key, value) => (key, value) }
 .toMap
```

Yields:

```
Map(a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3)
```

Comment: You can use `.lines` to split into lines and `_ split '|'` with single quotes if you're splitting on a single char.  Just a tiny bit cleaner.